# Checking signature on X509 certificate while verifying it

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, x509, signature, x509certificate2

Does CAPI check the signature on certificate (made by Root certificate or by a parent certificate) when a method X509Certificate2.Verify is called? Is the answer is Yes what CAPI-method performs the checking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`X509Certificate.Verify` method executes `CertCreateCertificateChainEngine` unmanaged function. The function performs all checks, including chain building, certificate path and signature validation for each certificate and revocation checking. CRL signatures are checked as well.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? In 4.5 this method is not used. Instead methods CertGetCertificateChain and CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy are called one after another. Today I made an experiment tried CertGetCertificateChain on good certificate and a certificate with damaged signature. And I've found that CertGetCertificateChain checks the signature...

Comment: Sorry, I typed from phone and mixed up correct function name. Yes, the correct function name is `CertGetCertificateChain`. But in any way, this function performs signature validation for each certificate in the chain.

Comment: for more information about the function, read Remarks section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376078(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't you know how function [CRYPT32.dll]CertGetCertificateChain defines the root certificate?

Comment: I mean when the function [CRYPT32.dll]CertGetCertificateChain builds a chain how does it recognaze that the chain has finished? Or it checks every certificate in chain if it is in the storage with root certificates?

Comment: the chain is finished (and only) when there is a self-signed certificate. Trusted Root CAs storage lookup is used only to determine whether the chain is trusted or not.

Comment: Thanks! Does the Trusted Root CAs storage lookup happen in function CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy?

Comment: yes, CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy uses Trusted Root CAs storage to determine chain trust.